# How do I get jstree to close/open if you click on folder icon not just the triangle icon

Tags: javascript, html, jstree

I'm using jstree on my html page I like to be able to open and close parts of the tree by clicking anywhere on a the row (i.e  ie, the small triangle icon, folder icon, and folder name.) rather than having to click the small triangle icon.

Here is a full self contained example to demonstrate the problem.Id like to be able to close the C:\Music folder by clicking on the folder icon or 'C:\Music' is that possible ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/songkong.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" class="source below">
$(function () {
$("#songchanges")
.jstree({
"plugins" : ["themes","html_data","ui","crrm","hotkeys"],
"core" : { "initially_open" : [ "phtml_1" ] }
})
.bind("loaded.jstree", function (event, data) {})
;
$("#songchanges").bind("open_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
data.inst.select_node("#phtml_1", true);
});
});
</script></head>
<body>
<div id="songchanges"><ul>
<li id="phtml_1">
<a href="#">C:\Music\</a>
<ul>
<li id="phtml_2">
<a href="#">KungFooFighting1.mp3</a>
</li>
<li id="phtml_3">
<a href="#">KungFooFighting2.mp3</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already use "ui" plugin, you could attach event handler to `select_node.jstree event`. And then use inside handler `$(this).jstree('toggle_node', data.rslt.obj[0]);` to open and close particular tree node.

Complete code will look like this:

```
$("#songchanges").bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
  $(this).jstree('toggle_node', data.rslt.obj[0]);
});
```

Comment: Thx @user2988142 but doesnt seem to work for me now I cannot open the tree at all

Comment: Its seem I need to use the wholerow plugin, but not implemented in jstree v1 and having problems with v2 will create a new question

Comment: You should remove `data.inst.select_node("#phtml_1", true);` from `open_node.jstree` handler. As it's closing tree every time you opening it.

Fully working sample - [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/eNUbuHO/1/edit)

Comment: thanks that works perfectly and jsbin.com looks like a useful tool as well

Answer (score 0):

jsTree 3.3.1 and IE7

Work for me with keydown

```
.bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
        var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        e.which = 39; // to right
        $('#myjstree a[id=' + data.node.id + '_anchor]').trigger(e);
```

...